# Upload files to Amazon S3 with Delphi using temporary security credentials

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 account and got SecretAccessKey, SessionToken, Expiration, AccessKeyId items. I would like to upload some files to the cloud, in the simplest way.

Have read a some docs regarding authorization headers (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) but still do not understand how to build them))

also, saw another example with Indy, so, please help to build the authorization header with these items that I have: SecretAccessKey, SessionToken, Expiration, AccessKeyId. It's ok to be with a "Transferring Payload in a Single Chunk" mode + "Signed payload option".

```
  FS := TFileStream.Create('c:\myfile.txt', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := ...; // please help
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Date := ...;   //what should I enter here?
    IdHTTP1.Request.Expect := '100-continue';
    IdHTTP1.Request.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    ...
    IdHTTP1.Put('http://'+BucketName+'.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.txt', FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What Delphi are you using ?, they are cloud components on Delphi 10 that make it quite easy.

Comment: Delphi XE8.  What components in D10 are used to implement aws auth ?

Comment: TAmazonConnectionInfo, These Cloud Components seems to be new on Delphi 10. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Developing_Cloud_Applications

Comment: wow, just found TAmazonConnectionInfo in XE8 lol)))  BUT, cannot understand how to make TAmazonConnectionInfo work with Temporary Security Credentials (security token)

Comment: should I use TAmazonAWS4Authentication.BuildAuthorizationString(... SignedStrHeaders from Delphi10 Berlin?

Comment: Sorry, AFAI we didn't built the AccountKey, the System's guy that created the account already gave it to me. I will write an answer showing the code that I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my routine to upload files to Amazon using the Cloud Components:

```
function UploadFile(File: TBytes; FileName: string; Bucket: string): boolean;
var Service: TAmazonStorageService;
    ConAmazon: TAmazonConnectionInfo;
begin
  try
    ConAmazon := TAmazonConnectionInfo.Create(nil);
    ConAmazon.AccountKey := 'Dih71bG09****************';
    ConAmazon.AccountName := 'AKIA***********';
    ConAmazon.QueueEndpoint := 'queue.amazonaws.com';
    ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint := 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
    ConAmazon.TableEndpoint := 'sdb.amazonaws.com';
    ConAmazon.UseDefaultEndpoints := False;
    Service := TAmazonStorageService.Create(ConAmazon);
    Result := Service.UploadObject(Bucket, FileName, File, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, nil);
  finally
    ConAmazon.Free;
    Service.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: so, you're ok with permanent credentials and do not use Temporary Security Credentials (security token)...  we're going to make our cloud client security working with tokens and maybe someone has used TAmazonAWS4Authentication ? we even do not see any example from embarcadero on how to work with it..

Comment: Yes, we have several Datasnap REST servers that are the only ones accessing to the S3 Storage, so our keys are not distributed out there. Are you sure that you really need to use the class TAmazonAWS4Authentication ?. I have read that Temporary Security Credentials work almost identically to permanent credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so, finally we've solved the issue:

1.Data.Cloud from Delphi10.1 Berlin should be used. It supports Amazon AWS4 security standard.
2.TAmazonStorageService.InitHeaders should be patched by adding the following code to enable temporary session tokens usage in the header:

```
...    
Result.Values['x-amz-security-token'] := //your session_token string; 
...
```

tested it from many sides, works fine now:)