# Downloading a file from Amazon with Delphi

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services

I am working with an API that provides me with the URL of a file and I wish to download the file to file or stream using Delphi XE.

The URL is in this form:-

```
https://xxxxxxx.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/Reports/414_20160114021919.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Expires=1478915858&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22123%20Test%20St%20Dallas__2016_01_14_03_16_00.pdf%22&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxx%3D
```

where I have xxxxxxxxx'ed out the sensitive security stuff.

If I paste the URL into Chrome, it finds the file and brings up the save dialog.

In my Delphi Program I'm using URLMon with the following code (happily burgled and adapted from answers to similar questions here on SO) :-

```
function TdmXXXXXXXXX.DownloadFile(AURL, AExtWithDot: string): string;
// returns temp file name or empty string if failed;
var
  sTempFileName: string;
  iError: integer;
begin
  sTempFileName := apmDM.GetTempFileName(AExtWithDot, True);
  iError := UrlDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(AURL), PChar(sTempFileName), 0, nil);
  if iError = S_OK then
    Result := sTempFileName
  else
    Result := '';
  showmessage(SysUtils.IntToHex(iError,8));
end;
```

The showmessage returns "800C000D"

In URLMon:-

```
$EXTERNALSYM INET_E_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL}
INET_E_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL            = HResult($800C000D);
```

So I'm assuming that the problem relates to stuff after the "?" in the URL, "AWSAccessKeyId=" etc.

Not sure where to go from here - searched here and with Mr Google ...

Cheers
Jeff

Comment: "the stuff after ?" is called a query string. It's critical that you know this simple term before diving into such programming. What version of Delphi are you using? If I recall, later versions come with a built-in component for connecting to S3.

Comment: Take a look to this question. Using Delphi's Cloud Component makes it much easier to access to Amazon S3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243529/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-delphi-using-temporary-security-credentials/40269435#40269435

Comment: I'd assume it had something to do with the stuff before the ":" ("https") because *that's* the protocol. Maybe there's something special you need to do to enable secure connections. It probably has nothing to do with Amazon. (You could confirm by attempting your code with some other https URL instead of an Amazon one.)

Comment: Rob is right. The error is related to `URLDownloadToFile()` not being able to understand the protocol portion of the URL (`https:`). `INET_E_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL` would typically happen when calling the Ansi version of `URLDownloadToFile()` with Unicode strings, or the Unicode version with Ansi strings.  Are you sure your declaration of `URLDownoadToFile()` is importing the correct version?

Comment: Using Delphi XE, so don't have Delphi Cloud Components.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE, so don't have Delphi Cloud Components.  @Rob - I've looked at URLMon I see that there is URLDownloadToFile, URLDownloadToFileA and URLDownloadToFileW and I have tested with each of these and all give the same error.  I have just been using ordinary string variables, which I understand default to Unicode strings in XE.  I've used PWideChar in passing the parameters (URL and FileName.  Sorry about delay in responding, had minor surgery and have difficulty working !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Though you'll typically find pointers to the [Indy TIdHTTP](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdHTTP.html) component, my personal favorite is including the Microsoft XML library (MSXML2_TLB), and using the [XmlHTTPRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874.aspx) component. If you use a [TStreamAdapter](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStreamAdapter.html) on it's responseStream property, you'll have a stream to a resource over an URL.

Answer (score 0):

I scratched all that I had done and restarted from scratch.

It all worked using URLMon and 
`URLDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(sReportURL), PChar(sTempFileName), 0, nil);`

I have pored over the code and can't see any difference between reported problem code and my final code.