# Delphi 10.4 Amazon aws S3 connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, amazon-s3

I have been using the function below to upload data to Amazon aws S3 bucket modifying code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243529/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-delphi-using-temporary-security-credentials).  All is fine in Delphi 10.3.3 but I get a connection error in 10.4.  I read [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.4) that there were changes to TAmazonRegion type (in Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI) but could not find a fix for my issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  function downloadFile(FileName_origin : string; Bucket: string; memo: TMemo): boolean;
     var Service: TAmazonStorageService;
     ConAmazon: TAmazonConnectionInfo;
     info : TCloudResponseInfo;
     download_stream : TBytesStream;
      bytes : TBytes;
   begin
      download_stream := TBytesStream.Create;
      try
       // filestream to tBytes
       download_stream.Position := 0;
       SetLength(bytes, download_stream.Size);
       download_stream.ReadBuffer(bytes, download_stream.Size);
    try
      ConAmazon := TAmazonConnectionInfo.Create(nil);
      ConAmazon.AccountKey := SECRETE_ACCESS_KEY; 
      ConAmazon.AccountName := ACCESS_KEY_ID;     
      ConAmazon.QueueEndpoint := 'queue.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint := 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.TableEndpoint := 'sdb.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.UseDefaultEndpoints := False;
      // storage objects
      info := TCloudResponseInfo.Create;
      Service := TAmazonStorageService.Create(ConAmazon);
         try
            Result := Service.GetObject(Bucket, filename_origin , download_stream);
         finally
            info.Free;
            Service.Free;
         end;
    finally
      ConAmazon.Free;
    end;
 finally
   memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(download_stream);
   download_stream.Free;
  end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone could use the help.  After some reading and digging I realized the fix was to specify the region specifically so add line below will fix the connection issue in 10.4
   ConAmazon.Region  := 'us-west-1';